# What is RAM Cache?

Tags: ram, 20.10, cache

I noticed this once I installed Ubuntu 20.10. There is 2.1GiB of memory used as "Cache".
[image]
I know the CPU, GPU and hard disk's have a cache. I know of swap memory, but this is the first time I'm seeing such a large cache relating to the RAM.

Could anyone help explain what this extra cache is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's copies of data read from or written to disk, in case you need them again for some reason.

The memory would otherwise be empty, so it doesn't cost anything to keep that data in RAM, it will be evicted when some application needs more memory.

Comment: Thank you. So the actual amount of RAM being used is 3.6GB. I guess it would cost electricity to keep that data in RAM :-)

Comment: Yes, but selectively refreshing memory would require additional logic, which would also require power. The "cache" memory can be turned into "free" memory simply by clearing it.